# What to do with access token(from the Auth Hash) in Omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, oauth-2.0, omniauth

I'm using Devise and Omniauth, and following the railscast(http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised) about it. It have only dealt with :uid, :provider. Nothing involves the **Token**(From Oauth2)? (https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema)

So, the problem is that what to do with the access token? For example, I use omniauth-qq(https://github.com/beenhero/omniauth-qq). And you can see that there is [:credentials][:token] in the Auth Hash

By the way, I only use omniauth for signing in users.

UPDATE:
I mean that I don't know what to do with the Token in rails. e.g, to store it in session or something else? Here is my code, and I have not deal with the toke at all. Is there any example avaible to see how to use the Token?

```
    def self.from_omniauth(auth)
      where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
        user.provider = auth.provider
        user.uid = auth.uid
        user.name = auth.info.nickname
        user.image = auth.info.image
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

I followed the same screencast and it works fine with no actions on the token.

If you only use it for sign-in you do not need to do anything with it.

You will need the token to take additional actions, such as performing requests on lists of friends,etc.

Comment: So even if the token get expired, nothing would bother?

Answer (score 0):

depending on what you want to do...for example, if you use ominiauth-twitter or facebook, those token is useful to authenticate urself and you can use the token to get extra information such as picture, nickname and many more.

Comment: I may not get my idea acrossed. I just have no idea how to use the access token in my code, like store it in session and update sometimes later. See my UPDATE.

Comment: probably you can just store in your cookie or database as well i guess(due to the security cz the if hacker get it,it might use the token to caputre information)..but you need a method to handle the access token because it might expired, for facebook, default is 2 hours but not sure current documentation is changed.

Comment: Is there any example to follow? I'm not quite sure about how to handle it...thanks!

Comment: o.O i tot you are following the correct railscast edy @@ hmm,btw ,http://railscasts.com/episodes/360-facebook-authentication this is the facebook example which you can take a look as well. maybe you can just proceed first since offline app not quite a big deal for tat.